# magento 1 CAPTCHA bypassed by bots

Tags: magento-1.8, captcha

Config: **Magento 1.8/CentOS**

problem: Bots log up with **CAPTCHA enabled** (spam is sent in Name field)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on another version of magento, after that I've swapped out all magento captcha's with Google invisible Captcha (using [this](https://amasty.com/magento-google-invisible-captcha.html) module). After that I've been spam free for a long time.